# neo4j: multiple values after with

Tags: neo4j, cypher, with-statement

I am getting started with neo4j and created a simple graph for practice. It contains students who are working in projects.

I would like to retrieve the students who are working in more than 2 projects and the respective projects, like this:

```
match (s:Student)-[w:WORKSON]->(p:Project) 
with s, p, count(w) as w_count 
where w_count > 2 return s, p
```

this gives me no result. However when I do this

```
match (s:Student)-[w:WORKSON]->(p:Project) 
with s, count(w) as w_count 
where w_count > 2 return s
```

i get the correct students and when I do this

```
match (s:Student)-[w:WORKSON]->(p:Project) 
with p, count(w) as w_count 
where w_count > 2 return p
```

I get the right projects. Glancing over the [with documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/with/) it says nothing about this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the documentation for [aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/) (like `COUNT`), and how they work with `grouping keys`.

For example, in your first query:

```
match (s:Student)-[w:WORKSON]->(p:Project) 
with s, p, count(w) as w_count 
where w_count > 2 return s, p
```

the grouping keys are `s` and `p`, so `COUNT(w)` will only count how many `WORKSON` relationships exist between a given pair of `s` and `p` nodes (that have at least one such relationship between them). That count will be always 1, so the `WHERE` test always fails.

In order to "retrieve the students who are working in more than 2 projects and the respective projects", try this:

```
MATCH (s:Student)-[:WORKSON]->(p:Project) 
WITH s, COLLECT(p) AS ps
WHERE SIZE(ps) > 2
RETURN s, ps
```